# Kivy - How do I set my app to be resizable up to a specified size?

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

How do I set my Kivy app to be resizable up to a specified size and no bigger than specified size but can be resized smaller than specified size?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is quite simple to implement, but I'm afraid you can't do it in "realtime" (at least not on Windows), because the size property is updated after you release the button from resizing i.e. "confirm" the final size. For that you'd need to get to WinAPI and other appropriate system APIs, but beware it'll be really resource hungry as with the system API you'd basically check for every change (even 300 → 300.0000000001 if the window manager would allow floats).

That being said, with Kivy you can make it quite easily when the behavior has to check for resizing and forbid actually making it bigger without disabling the `Window`'s resizing in any way.

You'll need to set the initial size first though (with `Config` before any other Kivy import) to make it consistent, otherwise you'll end up with a `Window` of size `800x600` and after you attempt to resize, then it'll scale down to `300x150`. The rest is just about a binding to either `size` or `on_resize` attributes of the `Window`

```
# set the initial size
from kivy.config import Config

MAX_SIZE = (300, 150)
Config.set('graphics', 'width', MAX_SIZE[0])
Config.set('graphics', 'height', MAX_SIZE[1])

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.core.window import Window


class My(App):
    def check_resize(self, instance, x, y):
        # resize X
        if x > MAX_SIZE[0]:
            Window.size = (300, Window.size[1])
        # resize Y
        if y > MAX_SIZE[1]:
            Window.size = (Window.size[0], 150)

    def build(self):
        Window.bind(on_resize=self.check_resize)
        return Button()

My().run()
```

Comment: I tried your solution, yet when I run my app I get an invalid syntax error for "from kivy.app import App".

Comment: @supreme that error has nothing to do with my example and it can be multiple things from mixed tabs&spaces in a single file(although that should be a specific error) to a broken Kivy installation. Make sure you copy the code block correctly into a separate file and try again. Or post the whole log. :)

Comment: @supreme glad to hear that :)

Answer (score 2):

I found a very simple solution when I was experimenting:

```
#:import W kivy.core.window.Window
<SomeWidget>:
    size_hint: None, None
    width: 300 if W.width <= 400 else (W.width - (W.width * .1))
    height: 300 if W.height <= 500 else (W.height - (W.height * .2))
```

That worked for me. I recommend to put all after the colon of the 'width' and 'height' in other place, because as you can see it consumes a lot of room in kv language.